# Do I need a separate API for result count instead I can reuse the get all API and take the count

Tags: angular, rest, api, django-rest-framework

I am beginner working on a DRF project with frontend written in Angular. 
I need to show count of "students" in the top bar.

I have these approaches in mind

1) reuse the existing (/students/ - GET) API endpoint and take the count of results. (may put overload for frontend)

2) reuse the existing (/students/count/ - GET) API endpoint and pass a parameter "count" to get the count.

3) write a new API (/get_student_count/ - GET) and get the count.

which would be the efficient approach in terms of RESTFUL API's.

Comment: first two approach sounds good, go for it

Comment: 2) is not a good solution as it prohibits a resource with id `count` in the `students` collection.